# Return string between square brackets and slashes inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to return string/values between square brackets and slashes inside like :

```
var valueX = "[/This is Value/]"
```

After catch, I need result : This is Value.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace` :

```
'[/This is value/]'.replace(/\[\/(.*?)\/\]/, '$1'); // "This is value"
```

Use the global flag (`//g`) to replace all occurences :

```
'[/a/] [/b/] [/c/] [//]'.replace(/\[\/(.*?)\/\]/g, '$1'); // "a b c "
```

Comment: ``'[/This is/] value/]'`` returns ``'This is'``.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var valueX = "[/This is value/]";
valueX.replace(/^\[\/(.*)\/\]$/, '$1');
```

Breaking it down, `^` matches the start of the line. `\[\/` matches the initial `[/`; the backslashes are to stop them being interpreted as special characters. `(.*)` means match zero or more `*` of any character `.` and save it as a group `()`. `\/\]` is the final `/]`, and `$` matches the end of the line. The `$1` in the replacement string tells it to use the first matched group, in our case the zero or more of any character.